# Consistency of Coordinate transformation with Conformal transformation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, coordinate-systems, field-theory, conformal-field-theory

I have a confusion about consistency of coordinate transformation with conformal transformation (in 2-dimensional spacetime.)

We know that a general tensor like $T_{\mu\nu}$ transforms as:

$T^{'}_{\mu\nu} = \frac{\partial x^\alpha}{\partial x^{'\mu}} \frac{\partial x^\beta}{\partial x^{'\nu}}T_{\alpha\beta}$

under coordinate transformation, and also if $\mathcal{O}$ is a primary operator, it should transform as:

$\mathcal{O}^{'}(z^{'}) = (\frac{\partial z^{'}}{\partial z})^{-h}
(\frac{\partial \bar{z}^{'}}{\partial \bar{z}})^{-\tilde{h}}\mathcal{O}(z)
$

But:

1. Does this two transformations are consistent? In the sense that an object can simultaneously be a tensor an obey coordinate transformation law, and also obeys conformal transformation law? It seems that It's impossible, if it's possible, can you show that these transformation laws agree with each other? and does a tensor could have any pair $(h,\tilde{h})$ for conformal transformation?
2. My second confusion, we know that conformal transformations are a subset of general coordinate transformation, so naively any tensor should obey conformal transformation laws too, but for example in CFT, Energy momentum tensor does not obey the exact form but has a term involving central charge and Schwazian derivative.

Comment: Your $T_{\mu\nu}$ is a tensor with respect to the algebra of diffeomorphisms. Conformal field theories do not have nearly this much symmetry so their primary operators are only required to be tensors under Lorentz transformations.